# Создание xml-схемы из xml-файла используя php

Tags: php, xml

Как из xml-файла создать xml-схему используя для этого на php?

Файл, который у меня есть:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<DECLARHEAD>
    <TIN>90000026</TIN>
    <C_DOC>S13</C_DOC>
    <C_DOC_SUB>001</C_DOC_SUB>
    <C_DOC_VER>07</C_DOC_VER>
</DECLARHEAD>
<DECLARBODY>
    <FIRM_EDRPOU>123456</FIRM_EDRPOU>
    <FIRM_NAME>ТОВ "Test connect"</FIRM_NAME>
    <FIRM_ADR>тест, 11111</FIRM_ADR>
</DECLARBODY>
```

Из файла нужно сделать такую схему:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">;
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>бла-бла</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="common_types.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="DECLAR" type="DeclarContent"/>
    <xs:complexType name="DeclarContent">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="DECLARHEAD" type="DHead"/>
            <xs:element name="DECLARBODY" type="DBody"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: думаю, вопрос нужно дополнить примером того, что у вас есть и того, что вы хотите получить в результате

Comment: у меня есть xml файл. (пример урезаный). 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
  <DECLARHEAD>
    <TIN>90000026</TIN>
    <C_DOC>S13</C_DOC>
    <C_DOC_SUB>001</C_DOC_SUB>
    <C_DOC_VER>07</C_DOC_VER>
</DECLARHEAD>
<DECLARBODY>
    <FIRM_EDRPOU>123456</FIRM_EDRPOU>
    <FIRM_NAME>ТОВ "Test connect"</FIRM_NAME>
    <FIRM_ADR>тест, 11111</FIRM_ADR>
</DECLARBODY>

Comment: дополни заданный вопрос

Comment: из него нужно сделать такую  xml схему (пример тоже урезаный):

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>бла-бла</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>

<xs:include schemaLocation="common_types.xsd" />

  <xs:element name="DECLAR" type="DeclarContent"/>
  <xs:complexType name="DeclarContent">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DECLARHEAD" type="DHead"/>
      <xs:element name="DECLARBODY" type="DBody"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

Comment: @МихаилГончарук А куда какие данные засунуть мы сами должны догадаться?